# MongoDB apply iterator with additional query to all results

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Is there anyway within mongo, via MapReduce or Aggregation to apply a second query based on the result set of the first?, such as an Aggregate within an aggregate, or new emit/query within MapReduce.

For example, I have a materialized path pattern of items (which also includes parentId), I can get all of the roots simply by:

```
  db.collection.find({parentId: null}
               .toArray(function(err, docs) {

               });
```

What I want to do is determine if these docs have children, just a flag `true/false`.  I can iterate through these docs using async `each` and check, but on large docs, this is not very performant at all and causes event loop delays, I can use `eachSeries`, but this is just slow.

Ideally, I'd like to be able to handle this all within Mongo.  Any suggestions if that's possible?

Edit, Example collection:

```
{
 _id: 1,
 parentId: null,
 name: 'A Root Node',
 path: ''
}

{
 _id: 2,
 parentId: 1,
 name: 'Child Node A',
 path: ',1'
}

{
 _id: 3,
 parentId: 2,
 name: 'Child Node B',
 path: ',1,2'
}

{
 _id: 4,
 parentId: null,
 name: 'Another Root Node',
 path: ''
}
```

This basically represents two root nodes, where one root node (`{_id: 1}`) has two children (one being direct), example:

- 1

  - 2

    - 3
- 4

What I would like to do is do a query based on `parentId` so I can get the root nodes by using `null` or by passing a `parentId` I can get the children of that and determine if the result set from this, any of the items contain children, example response for where `{parentId: null}`:

```
[{
 _id: 1,
 parentId: null,
 name: 'A Root Node',
 path '',
 hasChildren: true
},
{
 _id: 4,
 parentId: null,
 name: 'Another Root Node',
 path '',
 hasChildren: false
}]
```

Comment: Should be possible with the aggregation framework, can you show us the sample documents and what your expected output is from that sample collection?

Comment: Nice, I've updated with a sample collection and example response set

Answer (score 0):

You could try creating an array of the parentIds from the materialized paths that you can then use in the aggregation pipeline to project the extra field/flag `hasChildren`.

This can be done by using the **[`map()`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.map/#cursor.map)** method on the cursor returned from the **[`find()`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/#db.collection.find)** method. The following illustrates this:

```
var arr = db.collection.find({ "parentId": { "$ne": null } })
    .map(function (e){ return e.path; })
    .join('')   
    .split(',')
    .filter(function (e){ return e; })
    .map(function (e){ return parseInt(e); }),
    parentsIds = _.uniq(arr); /* using lodash uniq method to return a unique array */
```

Armed with this array of parentIds, you can then use the aggregation framework in particular the **[`$project`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/#pipe._S_project)** pipeline which makes use of the the **[set operator](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/#set-operators)** **[`$setIsSubset`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setIsSubset/#exp._S_setIsSubset)** which takes two arrays and returns true when the first array is a subset of the second, including when the first array equals the second array, and false otherwise:

```
db.collection.aggregate([    
    {
        "$match": {
            "parentId": null
        }
    },
    {
        "$project": {
            "parentId": 1,
            "name": 1,
            "path": 1,
            "hasChildren": { "$setIsSubset": [ [ "$_id" ], parentIds ] }
        }
    }
], function (err, res) { console.log(res); });
```

Comment: Nice, I'm testing this out.  I'm getting `undefined is not a function` for the `.join('')`

Comment: @dave Are you testing this within mongo shell or in Node.js driver?

Comment: I've tried with node-mongodb-native and mongoose in node.js